# Link to send a twitter DM

Tags: twitter

I have been searching and I haven´t found a straight solution.

It´s what url to place in an `<a href="#">link</a>`  So that it sends a twitter DM.

This is what I have but it´s not working properly:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=@tinybigstudio," id="twitter2" class="tip" title="Send a Tweet!">Twitter</a>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you could do is: http://twitter.com/?status=d+tinybigstudio
but that does not bring up the DM popup

Comment: I´ll just configure the original tweeter link and then try to change the button style: